# Deleting a TFS branch using git-tfs

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I have a feature branch in TFS that I've used locally with git-tfs using `git tfs branch --init`. (Normally I just use local git branches, but in this case I wanted to create a build with my changes, so a TFS feature branch seemed appropriate)

I've now finished with that feature branch, and I'd like to delete it from TFS and from git. I know how to delete it from TFS - it's the git side that's problematic.

I tried using `git tfs branch --delete Features/FeatureBranch`, which didn't complain, but subsequently every time I try to do a checkin, it fails with the following error:

```
D:\dev\git [31753]PS>git tfs checkintool
Unable to locate a remote for <http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection>$/Project/Features/FeatureBranch
You may be able to resolve this problem.
- Try using `git tfs bootstrap` to auto-init TFS remotes.
- Try setting a legacy-url for an existing remote.
```

Is there a way to remove these branches, so that I can go back to using `git tfs checkintool` normally?

I am using git-tfs 0.19.2.0 and git 1.8.5.2.msysgit.0

Comment: What do you get when you run `git tfs branch -r -all` to list all remote branches?

Comment: I think there is a bug in git-tfs :( Could you give us the content of the `[tfs-remote]` section of your `.git\config` file? Do you still have the data for the `default` remote?

Comment: Looking at the source code, git-tfs doesn't find a remote. Are you sure to have checkouted your `master` branch?
Feel free to open an [issue](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues?direction=desc&sort=updated&state=open) giving us more datas